# How to calculate route variations/permutations

Tags: permutations, calculus-of-variations

If I have 5 trucks and 10 deliveries to make per truck, that's 50 deliveries total, but how many different route variations could there be? You could give each truck the list of deliveries and they could do them in that order, or they could shuffle them around.. so how many times could they be shuffled per truck and in total?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few interpretations here. If you fix a set of 5 deliveries for a truck, then there are $5!=120$ different shuffles for each truck.

On the other hand, if you're asking how many possible delivery configurations total there are, then for each truck there are 5 choices, where each order gives a different configuration. This gives $50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46 = 254251200$ delivery schedules for a single truck.